# Added map layer. No error. Layer not visible

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I generate a map layer with the following code:

```js
    var GeoJSON = {};
    GeoJSON.type = "FeatureCollection";
    GeoJSON.features = [];

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 46],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 0.75,
            src: "~/icons/delivery-truck.png"
        }))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var machineGeoObject = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [data[i]["longitude"], data[i]["latitude"]],
            },
            "properties": data[i],
            "style": iconStyle
        }
        GeoJSON.features.push(machineGeoObject);
    } //end of loop

    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
           features: format.readFeatures(GeoJSON)
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(vector);
```

There is no error. When I call `map.getLayers()` in the console, I see the added layer.
The layer's property `visible` is `true`.

*Why can't I see the pinpointed locations with icons on the map?

Why do I only see a bare map?*

Answer (score 0):

You probably have features visible within 180 meters of lon/lat 0,0 in the Atlantic styled by the OpenLayers default style.  You cannot set an OpenLayers style via a GeoJSON, it must be set on the layer, or on the feature using `setStyle()`.  Also `featureProjection` on the format is only used in layer source setups, if you use `readFeatures` it must be specified there:

```
var GeoJSON = {};
GeoJSON.type = "FeatureCollection";
GeoJSON.features = [];

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: "~/icons/delivery-truck.png"
    }))
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var machineGeoObject = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [data[i]["longitude"], data[i]["latitude"]],
        },
        "properties": data[i],
    }
    GeoJSON.features.push(machineGeoObject);
} //end of loop

var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
       features: format.readFeatures(GeoJSON, {
         featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
       })
    }),
    style: iconStyle
});
```

Also check that your icon `src` url is correct (should `~` be `.` or `..` ?) and ensure `data[i]["longitude"]` and `data[i]["latitude"]` are numbers and not strings (use `Number()` if necessary).